# Дождаться конца анимации view.animate()?

Tags: android

Нравится этот способ вызова анимации. Но каким образом можно дождаться ее окончания?

Comment: Вроде там есть метод типа `addAnimationListener`

Comment: .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){...})?

Comment: @Jarvis_J Можно вопрос? Почему любые переменные в методе onAnimationEnd нужно объявлять финальными, или делать глобальными?

Comment: @keltkelt, все дело в "области видимости переменной". Метод `onAnimationEnd` принадлежит анонимному классу `Animator.AnimatorListener` и внутри он не видит переменных созданных в функции, где вы указываете `setListener` (исключение - `final` переменные). С глобальным объявлением такой проблемы нет.